# conda install doesn't ask for permission before installing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, githooks

I wrote a python script which is being used in `githooks/post-merge`, and its purpose is to install or update modules from a `env.yml` file that exists in the same repository. I used the following code:

```
    for module in modules_to_update:
        print("\n================================= Updating {} ==================================\n".format(module))
        update_command = ['conda', 'install', '{}={}'.format(module.name, module.version)]
        subprocess.run(update_command)
```

As can be seen, `modules_to_update` contains the modules that will be installed/updated. I didn't use `conda update` because I didn't want the updates to be automatic.

**The problem is**: I expected that conda will ask for permission to install/update every module individually, but it didn't work as planned. When I tried it to do so, every module did the same thing- proceeded without waiting for my input:

```
Proceed ([y]/n)?
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
...
```

I didn't use the `-y` flag so it should not work this way, and when I tried using the python script separately it worked just fine.

Comment: You're running without input attached to the subprocess's `stdin`, so it defaults to that `[y]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not attaching any `stdin` to the subprocess. Thus the subprocess likely does a `read()` call of some sort, gets an empty string (since nothing is attached) and defaults to that `[y]` yes default in the prompt.

You could do `run(..., stdin=sys.stdin)`, but it might be easier to run an interactive command via `os.system()`. (Don't use plain string joining to form a command line, though, to avoid shell injection.)

```
import shlex

update_command = ['conda', 'install', '{}={}'.format(module.name, module.version)]

os.system(shlex.join(update_command))
```